# Cannot resolve keyword 'post_id' into field. Choices are: comment, id, name, post_list

Tags: html, django

```
FieldError at /posts/1/
Cannot resolve keyword 'post_id' into field. Choices are: comment, id, name, post_list
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'post_id' into field. Choices are: comment, id, name, post_list
Exception Location: C:\Users\Emiedonmokumo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py, line 1481, in names_to_path
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Emiedonmokumo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Emiedonmokumo\\Documents\\mysite\\admin',
 'C:\\Users\\Emiedonmokumo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Emiedonmokumo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Emiedonmokumo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Emiedonmokumo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Emiedonmokumo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 13 Dec 2020 11:42:03 +0000
```

there keep directing me to this line of code:  c_number = len(Comment.objects.filter(post_id=pk)) …
please help me out, thanks

Comment: you are using post_id field in filter which is not available in Comment model you only have  comment, id, name, post_list fields.
instead you should use c_number = len(Comment.objects.filter(id=pk))

Comment: Share your models and *read* the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, there is no such field as `post_id`, there are only `comment`, `id`, `name` and `post_list`.

Likely you want to filter on `post_list`, so then the query should be:

```
c_number = len(Comment.objects.filter(post_list=pk))
```

Using `len(…)` is however *not* a good idea, since that will load all recors in memory and then obtain the length, this thus is inefficient use of bandwidth. You can make use of [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) to count the number of records at the database side:

```
c_number = Comment.objects.filter(post_list=pk).count()
```